# The Jenkinfile groovy facing issue with while loop with bash

Tags: linux, bash, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a script based on its result, I wanted to run the while loop, when its status changes need to break out of while loop. However I am seeing it entering the while loop. Any help on this would be very helpful

cat status.sh

```
echo "RUNNING"
```

cat status1.sh

```
echo "Aborted"
```

Jenkinfile.script as follow

```
script{
sh '''#!/bin/bash
        cd /Proj/scripts/
        pwd
        foo=0
        status=$(sh status.sh)
        echo "${status}"
        while [ "${status}" == "RUNNING|Queued" ]; do 
            sleep 10
            status=$(sh status1.sh)
             echo ".."
         done
'''
}
```

Result:

```
[Pipeline] sh
/Proj/scripts/
RUNNING
```

I think its not executing the while loop, any hint here.

Comment: This appears to be a bash question much more than a groovy or Jenkins one

Comment: any hint on solution?